# Extension of a Windows Form and make it part of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

If I search around in the Visual Studio Express Toolbox I find the TabControl and Tab. I want to extend the Tab so that I can give it a few standard features instead of doing it again and again for every time I add a new default tab.

In NetBeans (Java) you can extend any Swing Component, and then drag it into the GUI Builder for continuous usage.

How would I do this in VS Express 2012? It doesn't seem like I can.

If I make a class that extends Tab, I can't seem to drag it into the Toolbox. Do I just have to make a new "Custom Control"/"User Control" class like the C# Wizard gives me the ability to do, and it will take care of the rest? I am a bit new to C# and the VS Express IDE.

Comment: I think you create your own custom control and then add it as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165355(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: perhaps this might help: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSControlInToolbox.aspx

Comment: or maybe this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166364.aspx

Comment: not sure what you searched, but this was my search term: https://www.google.se/search?q=how+to+add+toolbox+item+visual+studio . What have you tried regarding visual studio?

Comment: Odd. I didn't find things like that at all. Most of it was pretty useless :\ But thanks so far. I'll try what's listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the "User Control" is the solution.

just create a new "user control" and add the Tab control in it then you'll find it appear into the tools box automatically.

then you can change the properties as you want.

Regards,